# ASP.Net AppSettings in Command of SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, sqldatasource

I have a `SqlDataSource` that I am trying to set an insert command with additional text after every table to switch for testing. I wanted to do this with an `<appSetting>` in the `web.config`.

When I do the following

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDRDocument" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ISNORTHConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"          
    InsertCommand="insert into DR_Document<%$ AppSettings:tablename %>
    (Columns) Values (Values)">
<asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I get

> Invalid object name 'DR_Division<%$ AppSettings:tablename %>'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Page_Load()

```
string tablename = DocumentRepository.Settings.getSetting("tablename");
SqlDataSourceDRDocument.InsertCommand="insert into DR_Document"+
tablename+" (Columns) Values (Values)";
```

In web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="tablename" value="_test"></add>
</appSettings>
```